# How to keep track of correct answers in React app using Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have built a React quiz that needs to keep track of correct answers. Each question has a correct value, 1 for correct, 0 for incorrect. When the user clicks on the question, the application makes a quick check and console logs if the answer is correct. I need to keep track of the amount of correct questions so I can show the user their score at the end of the quiz.
 I am using Redux to track this. I need to put each correct answer into an array, and return the length of that array to check how many questions are correct

I have set up the reducer and actions properly for the most part.

````
```
//Reducer
const initialState = {
  questions: [],
  answers: [],
  correct_answer: []
};
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {

    case "CORRECT_ANSWERS":
      let add_correct = state.correct_answer.find(
        item => action.payload.id === item.id
      );
      if (add_correct) {
        add_correct += 1;
      } else {
        return {
          ...state,
          correct_answer: [...state.correct_answer, action.payload]
        };
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

//Actions

export function getCorrectAnswer(correct) {
  store.dispatch({
    type: "CORRECT_ANSWER",
    payload: correct
  });
}

//Main Quiz component
 const correct_answer = useSelector(
    appState => appState.quizReducer.correct_answer.length
  );
```
````

When the variable is called using a useSelector, the length of the array is 0. When a correct answer is given it should increase by 1.

Comment: The statement `add_correct += 1;` seems weird to me, since the `find` method returns an item of the `correct_answer` array. This array seems to hold objects (with at least one property, named `id`).